# Deriving analytic expression for magnetic field & flow lines of bar magnet.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, physics, electromagnetism

How can we analytically derive the flow-lines of a normal permanent bar-magnet?

---

**Physics context & own approach:**

In classical electromagnetics we have the legendary Maxwell's Equations:

$$\begin{align}\nabla \cdot {\bf E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\\nabla \cdot {\bf B} &=0\\\nabla \times {\bf E} &= -\frac{\partial \bf B}{\partial t}\\\nabla\times {\bf B} &= \mu_0 \left( {\bf J}+\epsilon_0\frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t} \right)\end{align}$$

The situation in a normal permanent magnet far away from any electric field, we should have:

$$\begin{align}{\bf E} &= 0\\\bf J &= 0\\{\bf B} &= \cases{c{\bf \hat y}  \hspace{1.0cm}\text{(inside magnet)} \\{\bf B}(x,y) \text{ (outside)}}\end{align}$$
(c is constant : homogeneous magnet with constant microscopic dipole moment)

Can we use this to derive analytic expression for the flow-lines (or vector field $\bf B$) around a permanent magnet?

[image]
[image]

*Pictures show color mapped representation of **B** field around bar and horseshoe magnets acquired from a numerical optimization.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I suspect is a standard approach to such problems:

We have

$\nabla \times \mathbf B = 0; \tag 1$

then

$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf B) = 0; \tag 2$

there is a [standard identity from vector calculus which asserts that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities)

$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf B) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf B) - \nabla^2 \mathbf B; \tag3$

using this in concert with the Maxwell equation

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = 0 \tag 4$

yields

$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf B) = - \nabla^2 \mathbf B; \tag5$

(2) thus becomes

$\nabla^2 \mathbf B = 0, \tag 6$

where it is understood that $\nabla^2$ is applied to $\mathbf B$ *component-wise*; thus we have

$\nabla^2 \mathbf B_x = \nabla^2 \mathbf B_y = \nabla^2 \mathbf B_z = 0; \tag 7$

we may impose boundary conditions on the components of by by assuming

$\mathbf B = c \hat{\mathbf y} \tag 8$

in the iron bar, as is given in the text of the problem.  We also assume that

$\mathbf B \to 0 \; \text{at infinity}; \tag 9$

since the components of $\mathbf B$ satisfy Laplace's equation, this should be sufficient information to assure the existence of a unique solution for $\mathbf B$; but I strongly suspect it will not be very nice, analytically speaking.

To conclude, there is probably no "nice" formula for the field lines, but they can of course be plotted *via* numerical methods once we have found the vector field $\mathbf B$.

Comment: This is a very nice start. Thank you Robert.

Comment: @mathreadler:  Finding the solution will be tough, I'll warrant.  Probably need a Green's function on the exterior of the bar.  Probably get messy.  You might check out J.D. Jackson's book, it has a lot of stuff on problems like this.  Do you know it?  Cheers!

Comment: Yep I suppose it would be hard, that is why I asked it. I am an applied maths engineer and have gotten to a level I can write code and find my own numerical solutions by various methods, but my level of solving PDE:s analytically never got nearly as high. Thank you for the book hint! Will see if I can check it out!

Comment: @mathreadler:  it is a classic standard graduate level text--quite difficult but very thorough.  You should have no trouble locating a copy!